# Perl efficiency in writing in file

Tags: performance, perl

I am creating a database with some informations of files.

e.g: **file_name | size | modify_date** ...
I was thinking what is more efficient in this situation:

1) **For each file get the info and print them in my file**

```
foreach my $file ( @listOfFiles) {                 
    my %temporary_hash = get_info_for_file($file); //store in a tempoarary hash
                                                     the informations for current file
    print_info(%temporary_hash, $output_file);     // print the  information in my output file
}
```

2) **Store the info for every file in a hash and print all the hash at once**

```
foreach my $file( @listOfFiles){
    store_info_in_hash( get_info_for_file($file), %hash); // for each file, store the 
                                                             information in a global hash

   }
print_all_info(%hash, $output_file);                       //after i have informations for each file
                                                             print the whole hash in my output file
```

Comment: your program has four functions and I have no idea what they do. If you can explain little bit about them that may help us to understand your question properly.

Comment: Why are you so concerned with efficiency? I think I would write `print_info(get_info_for_file($_), $output_file) for @listOfFiles;`, which is equivalent to your first option. But please don't use a mixture of camelCase and snake_case.

Comment: i thought i was suggestive with the function names, i added some comments

Comment: @Borodin thank you for this advice!! I appreciate it!

Comment: Impossible to say given the information you've got. _usually_ writing data to disk is the slowest thing you can do, and so it's worth starting IO as early as possible. But there's also no particular advantage of having 'unneeded' data held in memory.

Comment: I would also like to write using @Borodin's way because this approach  is memory efficient than the other one.

Comment: I don't know which option would be more efficient for 1000 files let's say..

Comment: You may wish to write it in such a way that if 1000 files becomes 10000 files, it will still work without rewrite ( i.e. write files as you go ), but it really depends on how much info you need to store per file to determine whether or not you will be constrained by available memory.

Comment: It depends on whether your hash will fit in main memory.

Comment: Your edit made the code invalid. Comments are written with `#` in Perl.

Answer (score 3):

You are wrong to consider efficiency before you have even got your program working

You should write your code as clearly as possible and debug it. Only then, if it is not running fast enough for your purpose, you should put your code through a profiler to discover the bottlenecks that are taking the most time

The two options you show will probably not be very different unless your files are enormous

Answer (score 0):

Doing a benchmark test on the two options i got those results ( which, if I increase the information size for each file, will lead to even bigger differencies between the two).

[image]

Comment: Quite, and a ten-percent difference isn't worth bothering with

Comment: I don't trust benchmark results when I haven't seen the benchmark. Far too easy to get wrong. For example, did you actually keep the silly `print_all_info(%hash, $output_file)` calling convention? How big is your data? etc